# How to manage cache tiles deletion in mapbox on ios

Tags: ios, caching, mapbox, offline-caching, tiling

I'm looking for a solution in order to manage what tiles to delete from the user's device.

The options from mapbox is the wipe all tiles or to use one of the options: FIFO = first in, first out; LRU = least recently used; defaults to FIFO.

Both are less relevant to my needs, I'd like to have the option to actually manage them and say I'd like to delete from tile x to tile y.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API for this, but the cache is SQLite-backed, so you could always add one and remove tiles from cache according to specific SQL queries. The place to look into this is in `RMDatabaseCache`.